# Getting org.jclouds.rest.config error with storm-deploy

Tags: amazon-ec2, deployment

I would like to use [storm-deploy](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-deploy) to create Storm instances on Amazon EC2.

I've installed on an Ubuntu 13.04 system with Oracle Java7-JDK, and set the configuration files based on the [wiki](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-deploy/wiki).

After I call:

> lein deploy-strom --start --name test

I get the following error:

DEBUG jclouds - Found jclouds sshj driver
DEBUG jclouds - extensions (:log4j :slf4j :sshj)
DEBUG jclouds - options [:jclouds.regions "eu-west-1a" :blobstore-provider "aws-s3"]
ERROR logging - Exception in thread "main"
**ERROR logging - com.google.inject.CreationException: Guice creation errors:**

**1) org.jclouds.rest.config.SyncToAsyncHttpApiProvider cannot be used as a key; It is not fully specified.**

I tried to find out from source code but I have no experience with Clojure.
Could anyone tell me why I am getting this error? I would be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using JDK 7u51. This update broke something in [Guice](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/), a library that jclouds uses. You can see more details here:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCLOUDS-427

Move to an older JDK and it should work.